# Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.readBytes(Ljava/io/InputStream;) for PACT tests

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, pact

I'm getting this kotlin exception when trying to run some PACT tests using Java and not sure how to fix it please.

**Here the error :**

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.readBytes(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B

[image]

**EDIT**

I've updated my PACT dependencies to use more up to date versions, and I'm still getting the same issue, however only when I have the below dependency as part of it and not sure why.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

[image]

This is my current pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.hmhco</groupId>
<artifactId>update-catalog</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <rest-assured.version>3.0.0</rest-assured.version>
    <json-schema-validator.version>3.3.0</json-schema-validator.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${json-schema-validator.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <pactDirectory>target/pacts</pactDirectory>
                <pactBrokerUrl>http://pact-broker-hmh.devel.hmheng-qe.brnp.internal/</pactBrokerUrl>
                <projectVersion>${project.version}</projectVersion>
                <trimSnapshot>true</trimSnapshot>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And that's what I see when look for Kotlin after running maven dependency tree. The complete project can be found [here](https://github.com/francislainy/update-catalog/tree/master/src/test/java/com/hmhco/update_catalog/contract_tests).

[image]

[image]

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason you are getting that error (I'm assuming) is because you are mixing major versions of the Pact libraries.

```
<pact.version>3.5.24</pact.version>
<pact-jvm-provider-maven.version>3.5.9</pact-jvm-provider-maven.version>
<pact-jvm-maven.version>3.5.24</pact-jvm-maven.version>
<pact.jvm.consumer.junit.version>4.0.10</pact.jvm.consumer.junit.version>
```

You have versions 3.5.9, 3.5.24 and 4.0.10. You should use the same major version.

Versions 3.5.x are mostly written in Kotlin (probably version 1.2.x), while version 4.0.x is written using Kotlin 1.3.x.

I'm not sure why Sprinboot is impacting things, but maybe a Spring dependency is also bringing in a version of the Kotlin standard library.

The best thing to do is use version 4.0.10 for all the Pact libraries, then run the Maven dependency tree plugin and check that versions of the Kotlin standard libraries that are being used.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the dependencies and my post here but still getting the same error I'm afraid.

Comment: The fix is to force Maven to use the correct dependencies by adding the following:        ```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.72</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, adding these extra dependencies fixed the issue for us. :)